# Pre-1979 hard sci-fi children's or YA book with boxy functional spaceships

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, young-adult, childrens-novel, hard-sci-fi

I read a science fiction soft-cover book in 5th grade in 1979 or so that I was trying to track down.  I have very little recollection of the story, but that it was "hard" sci-fi, and probably involved some sort of space warfare.  I don't recall if humans were fighting other humans, or if they were fighting an alien species.  This book was probably targeted at children or young adults.

Within the story people traveled short distances through space in small boxy spaceships (because there was no air resistance necessitating streamlining), or in sleek needle-shaped ships that were capable of traversing the atmosphere of planets.  I recall that there may have been a scene where some people were trapped in either a boxy spaceship or a base on an airless planet with only a limited air supply.

Does this ring a bell for anyone?  Sorry I don't have more to provide.  Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

Sean

Comment: Ender's Game? [The Forge of God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forge_of_God)?

Comment: Sounds vaguely like [Assignment in Space with Rip Foster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rip_Foster_Rides_the_Gray_Planet). The good guys had "sleek" pointed ships, the bad guys were more rounded (not exactly boxy as I recall). There was a conflict between two human factions.

Comment: Nathan, you totally nailed it! It was most definitely the story you mentioned, but the 1969 paperback reprint called Rip Foster in Ride the Gray Planet. I hadn't recalled it was that story that promoted thorium as the future wonder fuel for atomic energy, though I remember picking up that idea from somewhere.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Nathan's comment should be made into an answer,  marked as the accepted answer by Sean G.

Comment: @JohnGHohengarten - I'm new to this, and can't seem to figure out how to "accept" Nathan's answer.  Can you provide some guidance for me to complete the answering correctly?  The StackExchange [help page on accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) shows a grayed-out check mark that doesn't appear for me on IE nor Firefox.  All I see in the far left column are the up and down  question clarity arrows and favorite question five-pointed star.  Nathan's answer only has a vote-up arrow and flag.  Thanks for pinging me on this...

Comment: Nathan needs to post his comment as an answer, instead of a comment. Only then will you be able to mark it as the accepted answer. Hopefully he will see these comments and will do it.

Comment: @Nathan: Could you make your response an answer?  I'd be happy to mark it as correct.  Thanks!

Comment: @SeanG. Wow I thought that was such a long shot I didn't bother to put it as an actual answer :) Glad we were able to find an answer for you!

Comment: @Nathan: IIrc, in "Rip Foster" the troop-carrying "landing boats" were box shaped. The "Snapper Boats" (read "fighters") were needle shaped. At least the Federation ones were, being "of American design, and showing the American love of clean lines".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Nathan mentioned in the comments, the answer is: [Assignment in Space with Rip Foster.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rip_Foster_Rides_the_Gray_Planet)

[image: Rip Foster- Rides the Grey Planet]

> Freshly graduated and commissioned Planeteer (the space-going
>   equivalent of a Marine) Lt. Richard Ingalls Peter ("Rip") Foster,
>   already contending with inter-service rivalry with the Space Force
>   (equivalent to Navy) crewmen with whom he serves, is tasked with
>   retrieving an asteroid made of pure thorium from the asteroid belt and
>   bringing it to Earth for use as fissionable material. In this he is
>   opposed by agents of the "Consolidation of Peoples Governments", who
>   also seek control and use of the asteroid.

Comment: I answered because Nathan never posted his answer in non-comment form.